# Y a-t-il une différence entre les termes « démagogie », « malhonnêteté intellectuelle » et « mauvaise foi » ?

Tags: sens

Ou ont-ils tous trois exactement le même sens ?

Answer (score 2):

Souvent on taxe de "démagogie" un politicien qu'on jugera trop populiste, si l'on considère que c'est une tare.

La malhonnêteté intellectuelle est une démarche intellectuelle en général consciente. Exemple: "Vous êtes populiste, tout comme l'était Hitler, donc vous êtes vous-meme hitlérien." Cela dit la personne qui utilise ce syllogisme peut simplement l'emprunter à quelqu'un d'autre et le répéter car il est perçu comme vérité dans le contexte d'un système de croyance (religieuse ou politique).

La mauvaise foi est une démarche intellectuelle consciente. Exemple: un faux témoignage afin de disculper, ou d'inculper quelqu'un.

Comment: Je n'aurais pas qualifié un faux témoignage de mauvaise foi. C'est plus un mensonge. Mais j'avoue que la nuance est tellement fine que j'ai du mal à produire des exemples flagrants...

Comment: Un mensonge peut être répété sans que la personne répétant ce mensonge sache qu'il s'agit-là d'un mensonge. Dans ce cas, la personne ment de bonne foi.

Answer (score 0):

**I**  démagogie

> [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9magogie) B. Usuel
>   1. Recherche de la faveur du peuple pour obtenir ses suffrages et le dominer. Faire de la démagogie. Par une démagogie facile, les impôts furent à peu près supprimés (BAINVILLE, Hist. Fr., t. 1, 1924, p. 184)
>
> [Ac.](https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/d%C3%A9magogie?page=1) DÉMAGOGIE n. f. XVIIIe siècle. Emprunté du grec dêmagôgia, dérivé de dêmagôgos (voir Démagogue).
>   Péj. 1. Comportement politique fait de complaisance et de flatterie à l'égard des souhaits ou des instincts des foules, sans souci du bien général et des intérêts supérieurs d'un pays. Faire preuve de démagogie. Tomber dans la démagogie. 2. Par anal. Attitude d'une personne qui cherche à s'attirer, par une complaisance excessive, la faveur d'un groupe.

La démagogie est une activité intellectuelle du politicien jugée ne pas relever d'une inspiration louable ; elle consiste à abuser presque « honnêtement » de la naïveté du peuple. Un politicien ne compromet jamais sa carrière dans des excès de démagogie. Le démagogue est au plus un beau parleur professionnel.

**II** malhonnêteté intellectuelle

> [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/malhonn%C3%AAtet%C3%A9_intellectuelle) malhonnêteté intellectuelle 
>   1.Subjectivité, insincérité, mauvaise foi, dans sa manière de raisonner ou de penser.
>   Quasi-synonymes : mauvaise foi (sens  : Hypocrisie dans les paroles, dans les propos. )
>   Antonymes : honnêteté intellectuelle

La malhonnêteté intellectuelle n'est pas  une activité ; c'est un tour d'esprit qui fait qu'une personne est encline  dans ses activités intellectuelles à cacher la vérité et à lui substituer des pseudo-vérités ou des mensonges dans le but de servir ses inclinations personnelles ou ceux d'un groupe, qui peut être toute une classe sociale. C'est de la mauvaise foi dans le domaine des activités supérieures de la pensée.  On peut dire que la malhonnêteté intellectuelle est de la mauvaise foi  mais on tend à réserver « malhonnêteté intellectuelle » pour des activité plus abstraites, plus fondamentales que celles pour lesquelles on utilise le terme « mauvaise foi ».  Par exemple on ne caractériserait pas l'acte de la  dissimulation des propriétés nocives d'une   substance par un responsable de laboratoire comme de la malhonnêteté intellectuelle mais tout simplement comme de la malhonnêteté.
Un démagogue, puisqu'il est aussi un intellectuel, peut parfois être porté à la malhonnêteté intellectuelle. C'est donc une caractéristique de la démagogie.

**III** mauvaise foi

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/foi)) Absence de sincérité, de franchise, de loyauté dans les intentions, dans la manière d'agir. Être de mauvaise foi. Une histoire altérée par l'ignorance ou la mauvaise foi; c'est mauvaise foi de votre part (Ac.)

La mauvaise foi est aussi un tour d'esprit par lequel une personne peut être induite à déguiser la vérité, ou à agir contrairement à ce que ses responsabilités demanderaient, cela dans le but de s'innocenter ou dans le but de servir ses intérêts ou pour d'autres raisons ; on n'invoque pas tellement la mauvaise foi en connexion avec les activités intellectuelles mais surtout dans le domaine des  affaires, dans le domaine de  l'interaction quotidienne des individus entre eux. Les actes de mauvaise foi peuvent être sévèrement punis lorsque sanctionnés par les tribunaux et autrement il peuvent compromettre la réputation de ceux qui les perpètrent (ex. dentistes qui cachent à leur patients les mauvaises conséquences possibles de certaines opérations; dans un tel cas on parlera de mauvaise foi ou tout simplement de malhonnêteté mais pas de malhonnêteté intellectuelle).

---

La démagogie est une activité passagère chez certain politiciens ; la malhonnêteté intellectuelle et la mauvaise foi sont des tours d'esprit, le premier caractéristique des intellectuels dans leur travail et le second caractéristique des  individus dans les affaires et dans leur interaction quotidienne entre eux. La démagogie est fondée sur la flatterie mais est  aussi empreinte de malhonnêteté intellectuelle. La démagogie n'est pas réprouvée sévèrement ni les actes de malhonnêteté intellectuelle le plus souvent mais 
ces derniers peuvent entrainer une mauvaise réputation ; les actes de mauvaise foi peuvent couter cher à leurs auteurs en termes de sanctions légales et/ou en termes de réputation.